# Why does not hide element ng-hide?

Tags: angularjs

I need to hide element if value is zero. I tried:

```
<span ng-hide="currentCount.appointment == 0">{{currentCount.appointment}}</span>
```

In `console.log(currentCount.appointment)` I see that after changes value of `currentCount.appointment` is zero, but why span block does not hide?

**Full code:**

```
request.success(function () {

$scope.currentCount = CounterNotificationService.setCounterInc('appointment', 'decr');
console.log($scope.currentCount.appointment);
});
```

Comment: Since you speak about `console.log(currentCount.appointment)`, I think `currentCount` is not a property of the current scope and thus doesn't exist and thus "undefined == 0" returns false. But without seeing more of your code, it's impossible to be sure.

Comment: If do `{{currentCount.appointment}}` in HTML I get `0`

Comment: Maybe some CSS is either overriding ng-hide, or overriding this elements display value?

Comment: what does `console.log($scope.currentCount.appointment)` give you? Note the "$scope"?

Comment: If you inspect the element in a browser, do you see an ng-hide class added?

Comment: It `console.log($scope.currentCount.appointment)` gives me 0,

Comment: I see only `class=ng-binding` in console

Comment: I added full code in question

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or in [Punklr](http://plnkr.co/) ?

Comment: Try to call `$scope.$apply()` after `$scope.currentCount = CounterNotificationService......`

Comment: May be need to send `$scope` to response AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

seems to work,

```
{{currentCount.appointment == 0}}
```

evaluates to

```
true
```

i created [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2gf8qrxg/10/) with the ng-hide and the ng-class approach

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<span ng-hide="currentCount.appointment == '0'">{{currentCount.appointment}}</span>
```

Comment: `currentCount.appointment == 0` is the same that `currentCount.appointment == '0'` Check the [difference](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) between `==` and `===`

Comment: What I want to say? Use === ?

Comment: @Alibabaev No. See my comment at the post above